# Cron job script not working

Tags: php, cron

So basically I have this cronjob script which worked on godaddy php 5.4, but in different host it does not work, tried different php versions too. I have correct path to cron, the host support said I did, even presented me with logs. Maybe there is some problem with this script? It basically adds energy points to user account.

```
<?php
include "../core.php";
//Fuel Refill (by default every 10 minutes)

$sqlusers = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE banned='No'");
while ($rowuser = mysql_fetch_assoc($sqlusers)) {
    if ($rowuser['fuel'] < $rowuser['fuelcapacity']) {
        $userfuelrefill = mysql_query("UPDATE users SET fuel=fuel+1 WHERE username='$rowuser[username]'");
    }
}

echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=../garage">';
?>
```

Comment: why does a cron script have html? can you run it from the command line? whats the cron call you use? that include would be my guess - try an absolute path. why loop at all,  cant you just run: `UPDATE users SET fuel=fuel+1 WHERE banned='No' and fuel < fuelcapacity`

Comment: show us the crontab line. As @nogad said, why html?

Comment: My path is: `/usr/local/bin/php /home/USERNAME/public_html/cron/fuelrefill.php` I am not a programmer, someone I bought this script from made, this, no idea why it would work on one host and not on another...

Comment: It's quite possible that your new host does not support (or have enabled) the mysql_* methods, since they have been deprecated or removed already depending on your PHP version. @nogad does offer a very reasonable solution as far as better efficiency would go.

Comment: this script could be reduced to 3 lines. but first i would check the include and @Blake's suggestion

Comment: Ok, I will ask my host what Blake told me to. I will shoot back message here as soon as I get response, thank you.

Comment: why not test it your self?

Comment: Because I have little to no experience regarding programming and similar IT stuff.

Comment: Stack Overflow supports people writing their own code; but we are trying anyway. if you got this from where, you should go ask the author. and if you run code from random strangers on the internet with out understanding it, anything could happen :-)

Comment: No, man I understand, any help is great, thank you. The code author is a lazy slob, with a bad support.

Comment: Can you give us what's in core.php (obviously with the sensitive information removed)? Do you have access to write to the files on this server? If so, I'd do a simple `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` to see if mysql is enabled or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mysql extensions are deprecated so try this PDO approach:

```
<?php 
require [full/script/path/]core.php;
$PDO = new PDO([INSERT CONNECTION STRING]);
$result = $PDO->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE banned='No'")->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
foreach ($result as $row)
{
   if ($row['fuel'] < $row['fuelcapacity']) {
     $query = "UPDATE users SET fuel=fuel+1 WHERE username= :username";
     $query = $PDO->prepare($query);
     if ($query->execute(array(':username' => $row[username]))) {
     } else { throw new Exception('SQL Query Failed [' . $query->errorCode . ']'); }
   }
}
echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;url=../garage">';
```

Now of course there are some things you will have to replace like the connection string and full path but this should work with PHP PDO enabled.

Comment: why not fix the other issues also? and unless he changes core.php to add a PDO connection this will fail

Comment: Unless `core.php` starts the connection he wouldn't have too. Also they said they weren't a programmer so this is the most minimally invasive solution I could think of to prevent further necessary modification. I mean we could make it a Laravel app and route it into the scheduler but inlining a framework into the stack overflow comments is just too time consuming lol... I hope you picked up my sarcasm and joke @nogad

Comment: Why encourage someone to run n queries when they can just run one? And one does not have to use a full path for an include. A relative is just fine.

Comment: Well I suppose you are technically correct. Although OP didn't specify if he wanted to change the actual structure of the solution. But I suppose your method works. I'd feel like I was stealing if I did, would you submit your solution as an answer?

Comment: Thank you for effort Nogad, Blake, Lemoney! My host support gave a solution (direct path): cd /home/USERNAME/public_html/cron/; /usr/local/bin/php fuelrefill.php